# Timezone shifting in postgres import

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I'm bringing in data from an Access table to a postgres table, using the ODBC export function. Postgres is creating the new timestamps as timestampz, and appears to be forcing my dates (which are UTC to begin with) to UTC, thus shifting everything about 4 hours. 
example == this record goes in as 2017/05/20 00:00:00 and gets translated to:
2017-05-19 20:00:00

Comment: If it's putting them in with timezone, then it will use the timezone of the database server's location, so if your dates are actually UTC, rather than your postgres instance's timezone, then you would need to amend that as you enter the data. Or you can simply change the postgres table's datatype to one without timezone and always use UTC for that data.

Answer (score 0):

postgres timestamp with time zone indeed forces dates to be stored in UTC. So if you had your time in UTC - you are good. The 4 hours shift you observe is not stored in db - it is due to your client timezone. Postgres shows (stored in utc) time according to your zone. EG:

```
t=# select '2017/05/20 00:00:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'utc';
      timezone
---------------------
 2017-05-19 20:00:00
(1 row)

Time: 0.368 ms
t=# set timezone TO 'utc';
SET
Time: 9.633 ms
t=# select '2017/05/20 00:00:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'utc';
      timezone
---------------------
 2017-05-20 00:00:00
(1 row)

Time: 0.353 ms
```